# $|A|=|A'|$ and $|B|=|B'| \implies |A'|+|B'|=|A|+|B|$ are well defined

Tags: elementary-set-theory

There are $4$ sets $A , A' , B , B'$ and $|A|=|A'|$ and $|B|=|B'|.$

$(|A|:=$  the cardinality of $A$).

Prove $|A'|+|B'|=|A|+|B|$ are well defined.

I read thousands times what is "well defined" but i really dont understand what i'm supposed to prove.

Here is my solution :

Since $|A|=|A'|,|B|=|B'|$ there are bijections :
$f: A' \to A , g: B' \to B$.

Define $$h: A'+B' \to A+B $$

$$x \mapsto \begin{cases} f(x), ~~x\in A' \\g(x), ~~x \in B'\end{cases}$$

$h$ is a bijection.
Is it correct ?

Comment: Before you define your $h$, what are $A'+B'$ and $A+B$?

Comment: @user10354138 $A+B := A \times {{1}} \cup B \times {2}$ and so $A’+B’$